Scaling covariance matrices for more computationally stable parametrization in gradient descent
I have a problem where I want to optimize a matrix $M$ using gradient descent. M is a covariance matrix, so it needs to be constrained to be SPD. For implementing this constraint, I am using parametrizations. Specifically, I am using the matrix exponential which maps from the unconstrained space of symmetric matrices to the SPD space: $exp: Sym_k \to Sym_k^+$. Then, I perform the optimization on symmetric matrix $U$, and obtain $M$ as $M=exp(U)$.
It seems to me that, in practice, this parametrization should work best when the true solution is close to the identity, because I think it's where this map would be closest to linear (since we can see this as solving the problem in the tangent space of the identity in the SPD manifold with Log-Euclidean metric).
Because of this, in my actual implementation I add a scaling to my parametrization, besides just the exponential. Specifically, I am using $M = c\cdot exp(U)$, where c is a constant chosen such that $c\cdot \mathrm{tr}(I) = \mathrm{tr}(\hat{M})$, where $\hat{M}$ is a coarse estimate of the solution. This way, the matrix $U = log(\hat{M})$ around which the optimization will he happening will be close to the $0$ matrix, i.e. to the linear part of the exponential map.
I am just wondering whether this scaling of the parametrization to get the problem closer to $U=0$ seems reasonable, since it hasn't solved my problems with the optimization routine, but that might be because of other difficulties with the optimization.

Look into "Semodefnite Programming", which deals precisely with matrices constrained to be symmetric psd, i.e., covariance matrices.
